# What do the four digit sequences in a JPEG mean?

Tags: image, image-processing, jpeg

So when I open a JPEG file in sublime or a text editor, i get a very long list of four digit sequences, such as:

```
84ac b7ac 5b2a ccda 5557 5541 af6a c5ae
17a8 d11c ec18 da5e c4c7 6b7a 9f25 896c
44b4 cf7b 52af 8ac9 4179 ec95 858c 0756
7395 3b36 71d7 99b3 d21e 2ae5 dbbe 72de
37d0 b2f3 b3d6 d352 cb46 7c3d c6de 7c47
0be9 a7ab 3f8b a7d7 a744 7cab d2fa d56f
c873 f49e bcb1 7469 d856 51af 743f 3fc8
f59e 4b58 5d79 f669 37d1 73e5 4d7f 5ecc
6f8b caf4 3c6e 8ad9 b69b e74e 6df5 823a
7cde a3f2 be27 b2e2 eeda d79d beea c785
b3b3 4e9c fcb1 b69e 9c73 871a c643 a29b
5880 6d15 f126 57a7 2af0 f93a 7a7d 1e47
522a d2c7 3d30 0bf3 ba4b aa69 a8b6 679a
fa47 3bbb c5d3 a466 e8a9 5ce3 a6d5 7c64
f4dc c34e 71dc c699 b4db 4ac6 fb39 41ae
8d7c dd0a 771d 1dae 5e7e 3f47 78f3 a6c3
52f3 162a 88a2 8e90 0578 c40e 010c 8c64
2ccc d5ed 96b3 55b2 a040 ed4b 3f9a f519
375e 3317 bb3d b979 4b7d 0e0d 12fb 4e37
63cd db07 cabe b3e4 749f 0bb7 b3de f4f1
f29a 7d4f 439e fc97 a7e9 dbc3 a60a fa73
```

What do these sequences of 4 digits mean? I tried googling this but haven't got an answer. Does each one relate to a pixel? or the color of a pixel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the text editor's representation of the binary code that makes up the image file.   Each set does not necessarily have to relate to one pixel or one detail of a pixel.